# How to create a HTML canvas via form

Tags: php, html, canvas

I want to get size of canvas from user.. When user gives a specific pixel size, the canvas will be drawn of that size.. I am trying to run this code but its not working.. I tried to get it via form and also defined values in PHP.. It is not working in both of this way..

```
<html>
<body style=" background: lightblue;">

<?php

//@$height=['$height'];
//@$width=['$width'];

$h=420;
$w=420;

?>


<center>
<form name="test" action="Untitled-1.php"> 
Please enter height : <input type="text" name="height"> <br>
Please enter widht : <input type="text" name="width"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"> <br>
</form>
</center>

<!-- <canvas id="canvas" width="420px" height="420px" style="background: #fff; magrin:20px;"> -->
<canvas id="canvas" height=<?php '".$h."' ?> width=<?php '".$w." '?> Style="background: #fff;">
<!-- <canvas id="canvas" height=<?php '".$height."' ?> width=<?php '".$width." '?> Style="background: #fff;"> -->

Browser does not support canvas 
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to echo your php variables out in the canvas tag: `<?php echo $h; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing the output in PHP.

Replace

```
<canvas id="canvas" height=<?php '".$h."' ?> width=<?php '".$w." '?> Style="background: #fff;">
```

With

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="<?= $h; ?>" width="<?= $w; ?>" Style="background: #fff;">
```

If not working too, you don't have `short_open_tag` enabled, so then replace `<?=` with `<?php echo`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this expression :

```
<?php echo '<canvas id="canvas" height='.$h.'  width='.$w' Style="background: #fff">'; ?>
```